# Set breakpoint on COM class method in windbg

Tags: windows, com, windbg

Is there some way, similar to "bm Module!Symbol" to set a breakpoint on a specific method of a COM class in windbg? It looks like a COM DLL only exports four symbols (DllCanUnloadNow, DllGetClassObject, DllRegisterServer, and DllUnregisterServer), so the usual "bm" approach doesn't work. I'm assuming there's some other way to do it, but I haven't been able to find it in the past hour or so.

Comment: Do you have symbols for this COM DLL? If you only see export functions, this means you have no symbols. Just find symbols and you should be able to set a breakpoint using regular 'bp' command, assuming the module is already loaded. If module is not loaded yet, set breakpoint on module load: "sxe ld:MyModuleName.dll", then when module is loaded set the breakpoint using "bp MyModuleName!MyClass:MyMethod".

Comment: I don't have any debug symbols for the library, unfortunately. Is there some way to extract the addresses of the various methods on the COM class? It would seem like there would have to be.

Comment: Without symbols there is no good solution. If COM object is instantiated in the same appartment or COM object is configured to support neutral appartment model, you can get the pointers to the methods out of the virtual method table for the COM object you instantiated. However it object is from different appartment (which means your code gets an RPC proxy, not a real object) then finding an implementation is much more difficult -- I wouldn't be able to trace through RPC proxies/stubs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use bu (unresolved breakpoint).  I believe the syntax is as follows, but my memory may be rusty:

```
bu MyDll!MyClass::MyMethod
```

Comment: Hmm, it might be something slightly different. When I try that and then start executing, I get "Breakpoint 0's offset expression evaluation failed. Check for invalid symbols or bad syntax. WaitForEvent failed" right after all the module/symbol loads finish.

Comment: Bummer. Oh well, I'll see if I can cook up a Plan B.

Answer (score 0):

COM methods are still regular symbols, even if they're not exported. Say you have `MyFoo.dll` which contains a `MyBar::Baz()` method.  In WinDbg if you have symbols loaded you can e**X**amine the symbols with:

```
X MyFoo!*Baz*
00007ffa`204cbb00 MyFoo!MyBar::Baz (void)
```

You can set a breakpoint on it with

```
bp MyFoo!MyBar::Baz
```